# How to send back data to same form when user hits submit button

Tags: php, oop

Ok,

So I have a form that is on page 'index.html'. The user submits the form, which then goes to a processing page, say 'processing.php'. I would like call this processing page from the index page, assign the return value to a variable, and go from there.

The problem I am having is that the page should only be called when the user submits the form on index.html page. So how can I call this processing page before the page actually gets submitted and sent to that page? (I don't know if I am making sense, but I want the user to hit submit, then that action calls on processing page which returns the result back to the index page to display)

Any suggestion on how to approach this?

Comment: See my question below on security concern? This would be the easiest way out, I just have question on the security of this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your index.html page is really index.html and not a redirect to a PHP script, you're going to need something that can dynamically update the DOM, ie: Javascript. You can go with JQuery AJAX functions to return the results to the index.html page and update elements on the page.

Or you could just make an index.php that submits to itself, and only returns the form results if your form variables are present in $_POST.

Comment: ok, supposing I go with the second option (NON-jquery). How secure is it putting php code to process requests in the same page as the HTML? Say the PHP will be handling sensitive data, would this method be safe enough to use? Could anybody get a hold of that php code?

Comment: No, the PHP code is all processed server side. As long as your properly sanitize your user input, you should be fine. There is no more risk in exposing your code by submitting the data to a separate processing script than but submitting the code to the same page.

Comment: This sounds like a winner. Thanks a lot all!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jquery](http://jquery.com/) with [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Or, you just submits normally:

```
<form action="processing.php">
```

and in your `processing.php`, after the "processing", it redirects to index.html

Comment: Yeah, I was really trying to avoid getting jQuery and ajax into this, but it's looking like I ll have to.

Comment: It sounds like he wants to return some result set to index.html, so redirecting back to the page won't work, because index.html is a static page, unless he has a redirect to rewrite index.html to some PHP script.

Comment: @Canuteson oh! sounds like that indeed. Not very clearly though. But if its that so, the solution is JS.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of approaches you could take. But you are limiting yourself by using a `html` file for the index, so you should rename the file to `index.php`

**Store the return message in a session**

```
# processing.php
session_start();
$_SESSION['message'] = 'Thanks for submitting the form';

//redirect to home page
header('Location: index.php');

# index.php - you will need to use php files to clear the session
session_start();
echo isset($_SESSION['message']) && !empty($_SESSION['message']) ?
  $_SESSION['message'] : '';

//clear the session
unset($_SESSION['message']);
```

**Set a GET parameter in the URL**

```
# processing.php
//redirect to index
header('Location: index.php?processing=true');

# index.php
if(isset($_GET['processing'])) {
  echo 'Form successfully submitted.'
}
```

**Submit the form to itself**

If you submit the form to itself (i.e. index.php), you can do the processing in this file and do something like

```
# index.php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
 //process form
 // ...

 //echo message
 echo 'Form submitted successfully.'
}
```

**Use AJAX to submit the form to processing.php**

I notice the above poster suggested this. You should look up the jQuery `ajax` method and in processing.php, echo out a message. Then in the success function of the 'ajax' method, display the message

```
success: function(data) {
  $('#results').html(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following jQuery:

```
$("form").submit(function () {
  $.post("processing.php", $(this).serialize(), function(response) {
    $(this).after(response);
  });
  return false;
});
```

This hijacks the submit method (`return false` prevents default) and then POSTs the data to your page and inserts the response after the form.

Comment: Simon, this method seems pretty interesting. I am definitely going to try this out.

Answer (score 0):

1) First Method

You can put below code

```
header("location:index.html");  return;
```

in the end of code in processing.php file which helps to redirect index page after task completed.

2) Second Method

Rename your index.html file into index.php.
Now include processing.php file in index.php file then your code similar as follows:

```
include("processing.php");
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
User Name   :   <input type="text" name="userName" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Enjoy!!!